# Is it possible to create custom query/pivot table in Oracle Peoplesoft?

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

As per title, is it possible to write my own query in OracleSQL Developer and then plug it into Oracle Peoplesoft? Or is it possible to have a pivot query in Peoplesoft?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using a view.

After that you will create a new Query using your view, and if you want to, use the query as datasource for your pivot grid

Answer (score 0):

Oracle PIVOT clauses are not supported, nor are any other database pivot-like clauses.  And as suggested by Walucas, you can use a view with the PIVOT clause already written and then query the view.  An alternate approach would be to use a series of left outer joins where each join is to the same table, each with a mutually exclusive set of rows.  This is a hammer-like approach and very inelegant, but you can do this without having to create a view.